# Parse through HTML response from getUrl()

Tags: bixby

I am trying create a Bixby capsule that can retrieve values from a website. The getUrl() response will be in HTML. Is there a way to parse through the HTML response for values or somehow converting it to JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that through Bixby using regular expressions, but you would need to parse everything through some regex processing in your code when you get a response from getUrl(). There isn't a way to automatically convert an html response to json.  Here are some [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+html+parsing) to parsing html responses with regex.

Comment: Thank you Pete. In short, Bixby does not offer utility to parse HTML to JSON object, you have to do it in the JS. It's better to find out if the website has API interface.